# Regex to match multiple occurrences of pattern and disregard content in-between

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match multiple occurrences of a pattern in a string and disregard the in-between content.

For example, in the string below:

`"35264208011:5:1044512:0.1078, 1044512:6:3526415811:0.0444, 699905011:6:3526420011:0.0544”`

I want to get all the occurrences of `1044512` and their accompanied rate (i.e. value with the decimal)

My desired output would be:
`"1044512:0.1078, 1044512:0.0444"`

I have tried '1044512:(.*?)0\0000' but seems to be missing something significant. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Do you need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

try this regex :

```
(1044512)(?:.*?)(0\.\d*)
```

in your example this will give you this matches :

```
match 1 : 1044512:0.1078
     group 1 : 1044512
     group 2 : 0.1078
match 2 : 1044512:6:3526415811:0.0444
     group 1 : 1044512
     group 2 : 0.0444
```

then all what you need to do is to concatenate **group 1** with **group 2** like this :

```
$1:$2
```

this is a [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/CE2xPT/1)